# How to publish excluded files in Visual studio during deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure-devops

I have an MVC5 project and I use Visual Studio 2019, to do my deployment using the deployment profiles.

In the root of the folder I have a few files (e.g. png files) that I prefer not to see in the Solution Explorer. However, I need them to get published.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove them from solution file or csproj file but leave them in source control. However, please bear in mind that by default publish profiles are excluded from source control by default gitignore for visual studion. This is because they contains sensitive data and as this they should not be stored in source control. If you need them to deploy code and you use Azure DevOps please consider using [secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops).

If you want to include files which are not in the project you may follow this [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Deploying Extra Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files). There you find information how to modify publish profiles to include additional files:

```json
<Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="ExtraFiles\**\*" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Note: you might need to use:

```json
<_CustomFiles Include="..\ExtraFiles\**\*" />
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Just to clarify I am talking about other files not the publish files. Imagine I have a file called apple-touch-icon.png in the root of the solution. I want to be able to deploy this but I don't want to see it in the solution explorer. If I exclude it or remove it from project file, then it won't get deployed.

Comment: @Stackedup I missed that point. However I have also solution for this. Please check my update answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. Actually the post/pre build doesn't help because it doesn't effect the publish. However, I found the solution. Please update your answer with this link and I mark it as solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files